# Android: Adding SyncAdapters to existing Account

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-syncadapter

I want to split up functionality from a bigger SyncAdapter to the corresponding Apps. Therefore i now have a single App which contains the Authenticator and a SyncAdapter which syncs core data.
The plan is now, that other Apps also contain SyncAdapters which sync the app-specific data.

Reading https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-single-account-multiple-application-prescription i tried to add a second adapter like suggested but i'm having the issue that it doesn't show up in the Account's SyncAdapter list.

UPDATE: just figured out that i used the same contentAuthority in the two SyncAdapter declarations (as i only have a single contentProvider) and of course same account-type which leads to a identical declaration and this could be the problem that my second syncadapter just overrides my first one. 
still investigating this theory

Answer (score 0):

as already mentioned in the update - the cause was the identical declaration.
you have to use a different contentAuthority (ContentProvider) for each SyncAdapter to get this working!